# Recover x-pagination with Angular

Tags: angular, http-headers, httpresponse

I try in Angular to recover 'x-pagination' informations from my WEB Api (with http get method).

Data are well present in the web api response as you can see below (from browser panel).
[image]

I do my get request in Angular like this :

```js
public getAll(pageNumber: number, pageSize: number){
    const api: string =  this.apiAddress `truckParameters?PageNumber=${pageNumber}&PageSize=${pageSize}`;

    const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({'x-pagination': 'application/json'}),
    observe: 'response' as 'response'};
    return this.httpClient.get(api, httpOptions).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.info('Header :' + JSON.stringify(response.headers.get('x-pagination'), null, 4));
      }
    );
  }
```

I can read "cache-control","content-length" and "content-type" but I'm not able to read the "x-pagination" informations.

What I'm doing bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to expose the custom header in the "Startup" file of my Asp .net Core Web Api.

Thereby, Angular can read the "x-pagination" header element.

For more informations : [Enabling Custom Header with CORS Configured](https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-add-custom-headers/)